# Zip and download files from Amazon S3 with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Laravel project which allows to upload photos and they are stored S3 bucket.

At particular times, it's needed to download an entire album which is a folder in S3 bucket storage. So, it should be downloaded as a ZIP file that includes photos of that album.

I managed to do this when these are stored on local storage.

```
 public function downloadZip() {
            $files = glob(public_path('js/*'));
            Zipper::make('mydir/mytest3.zip')->add($files);


            return response()->download(public_path('mydir/mytest3.zip'));
 }
```

But, in S3 bucket, that method is not working.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What method were you using on local storage?

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated the question :)

Comment: OK, yeah, that's not going to work. You can't use `glob` against a S3 bucket. There's not a really easy way to do what you want - you're going to need to download the files to your server and zip them there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368119/zip-an-entire-directory-on-s3 for why and a possible method.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks! Will check that!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Amazone service feature [Async transfers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-transfer.html#async-transfers). This will help you to get the s3 files and after that you can use your `Zipper` logic to zip that files.

Answer (score -1):

AWS exposes SDKs for different platforms like Java/PHP etc to interact with different AWS Services.

You need to access https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/ for your PHP code to copy files from s3

Comment: Laravel has built-in handling for S3 via the Storage facade.